How to Change my CyberPowerPC Keyboard Backlight Settings
I have a CyberPowerPC and the keyboard that came with it. There used to be a constant backlight, but after I hit an accidental hitting a key combination, it now flashes every time a key is pressed. How can I make it go back to a static backlight color?
I have tried Function+Insert as I found online and it does nothing, instead of fixing it.
Update: Hitting Fn+(A Number) will change the backlight settings
